# How do I implement a jquery scrollbar for phpbb forum within an iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, phpbb

I have a very specific case here.

I need to implement a good looking jquery scrollbar for an iframe that holds the forum on a website.

The news and bulletin sections can hold jquery scrollbars just fine, however I cannot get the plugin working for the forum section (third button). If I put it around the iframe, it scrolls only a little bit. If I enable iframe scrolling, then it looks ugly. If I try to put the jquery code for, let's say, tinyscrollbar on the phpbb theme files, then it simply does not show up.

I looked for some jquery mods for phpbb which would allow vertical scrollbars and did not find any. I tried different combinations with my existing set of tools and failed.  Can someone help?

Comment: why are you using an iframe in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could always add the scrolling to your iframe tag like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://foobar.com" height="800" width="400"></iframe>
```

and then use http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/

Comment: iframes look ugly and are dated technology no mater how you use them. and are bad for search engine rankings.

Comment: Sorry, posted before I was done.. Use the jquery plugin in combination with it.

Comment: What are alternatives to iframe?

Comment: Thats my other answer. You get the whole html with jquery with a get request and apply it to a div. Tons of guides out there :)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer would be on Dagon's line. Like to use Jquery instead.

```
$.get('http://foobar.com', function(data) { $('#divIdHere').html(data); });
```